# PHP: Sending bulk emails from a query result

Tags: php, mysql, email

How can I send an email to all results from a certain field at once?

Answer (score 2):

The [PHP Manual's mail() page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) suggests using either [Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) or [Mail_Queue](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue) Zend packages for sending large quantities of emails. I'd suggest you take a look at those, and see if they do what you need.

EDIT: Specifically, take a look at [Mail::send()](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php) which takes either a comma separated string or an array of emails to send to.

Answer (score 0):

Most emailer allow you to separate email with a comma, you may also want to look out for bulk emailer script, there are many of them out there.